# <body> bigger than what it should be

Tags: html, css

The `<body>`, `<html>`,... and other elements are normally sized at 385px (as it should be) but the content area is bigger though.

I don't understand where the problem comes from...

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9487343/2012-06-16%2019.09.00.jpg

Box model respected: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9487343/2012-06-16%2019.31.09.jpg

Comment: padding/margin/border inside? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: I don't seem to understand your question. What are , , and ... ?

Comment: @kowalt: Please see http://w3fools.com and don't link to them ever again :)

Comment: do you see the links now? I checked all elements with the chrome inspector to see if a margin was the problem source but no. Look, the html and the body are at the right size (blue color on the picture).

Comment: In my opinion box model is very well explained, although I also don't recommend this CSS tutorial as a entirety :)

Answer (score 4):

You should read up on the CSS [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html). From your brief description, I suspect it's due to some padding you've added to your body, or one of the child elements. You might try setting the following CSS in your document:

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You have some element overflowing the body container. Setting `overflow: hidden;` on the body element in your CSS should mask the problem. This can happen when you set the child element's width to 100%, but also give it padding, effectively making it wider than it's parent element (`body` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that any height or width does NOT include paddings, margins and border widths.
And large content could push a box wider than what is was set for.